# Unable to access elements inside angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use below code to access button inside a `mat-menu` by class name but doesn't work:

TS:

```
constructor(private elem:ElementRef){
}

ngOnInit(){
 let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.role-menu');
 console.log(elements);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1">Test</button>
<mat-menu yPosition="below" #menu1="matMenu">
<button mat-menu-item><mat-icon>account_box</mat-icon> My Profile</button>

 <button class="role-menu" mat-menu-item><mat-icon>lock</mat-icon> API Keys</button>

<button mat-menu-item><mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon> Logout</button>
 </mat-menu>
```

Created a demo Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5w1yzq)

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Angular' way to access template contents is via the `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChidren` decorators and template references:

HTML

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1">Test</button>
<mat-menu yPosition="below" #menu1="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item><mat-icon>account_box</mat-icon> My Profile</button>

  <button #roleMenuButton class="role-menu" mat-menu-item><mat-icon>lock</mat-icon> API Keys</button>

  <button mat-menu-item><mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon> Logout</button>
</mat-menu>
```

TS

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
...
@ViewChildren('roleMenuButton') roleMenuButtons: QueryList<ElementRef>;
...
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let elements = this.roleMenuButtons.toArray();
  console.log(elements);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out eventually. I have a case where I needed to select normal buttons inside component html with class `role-menu` also the one inside material `mat-menu`.